plotly dash, css file not connecting
I am attempting to move from plotly to dash, and would like to connect a css file to style my dashboard. The app renders fine with my file structure; app.py and index.py in the main folder, and an additional style.css file in the /assets folder.
however, when I add some styling to the css, the main dash app does not “automatically render it” as the documentation states it should.

my dash version is later than 2.13; specific version is 2.18.1
I have tried both including and excluding name in the Dash() call
I have tried specifically stating assets_external_path=“/assets” in the Dash() call
I have tried setting external_stylesheets=["/assets/style.css"] in the Dash() call

and it still does not connect to the style.css file. does anyone have any tips or tricks to get dash to recognize and connect with the css file?

solved, turning debug mode off fixes this. app.run_server(debug=False)
kudos to @spriteware in the plotly community forum!
